# Tracking conversions using the action_target_id doesn't seem to work anymore

Tags: facebook-ads-api

When using the action breakdown to view the offsite conversions:

```
act_[ACT_NUM]/reportstats?date_preset=last_3_days&increment=1&data_columns=['campaign_group_id','campaign_group_name','actions']&actions_group_by=['action_type','action_target_id']&limit=1000
```

amongst the response will usually be something like:

```
...
    {
      "action_type": "offsite_conversion.lead", 
      "action_target_id": "[object_id_1]", 
      "value": 3
    }, 
    {
      "action_type": "offsite_conversion.other", 
      "action_target_id": "[object_id_1]", 
      "value": 1
    }, 
    {
      "action_type": "offsite_conversion.other", 
      "action_target_id": "[object_id_2]", 
      "value": 7
    }
...
```

We've been using the `action_target_id` to link to conversion pixels by their id and this still *mostly* works. However the facebook report on conversion pixels seems to have added the action values for stats with the same tag as the conversion pixel but with different `action_target_id`s. For example the above referenced `object_id_1` for the lead stat appears to link to a creative but its value has been added to the total conversions for one of the lead tagged conversion pixels attached to the account. Not sure if it's relevant but this seems to only be happening to multi product ads on the accounts I've looked at.

Anyone have an idea why this might be the case and whether or not it is possible to consistently link the response from the action breakdown in report stats to conversion pixels?

Comment: Is that the same as this bug report here? https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1607831762764812/

Comment: Good catch, it looks like a similar issue.